# Error 400 Bad Request in Post HTTP Request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a POST request but I keep getting error 400 Bad Request. In Postman it works I have raw body like this:

```
[
  { 
    "athleteId":"16198",
    "departmentId":"3",
    "teamId":"278"
  }
]
```

Api request

```
static Future<List<Athlete>> insertPresences(
      int athleteId, int departmentId, int teamId) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://my_domain/path'),
        headers: <String, String>{
           'Authorization': 'Basic ..',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "athleteId": athleteId,
          "departmentId": departmentId,
          "teamId": teamId
        }),
      );
      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        List jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

        return jsonResponse
            .map((_insert) => Athlete.fromJson(_insert))
            .toList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e.toString());
    }
    return insertPresences(athleteId, departmentId, teamId);
  }
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Response status: 400
I/flutter (20754): Response body: {"timestamp":"2022-10-28T12:46:39.969+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":".."}
```

If someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the outer brackets that you show in your raw body.
Simply add the brackets, like

```
    body: jsonEncode([{
      "athleteId": athleteId,
      "departmentId": departmentId,
      "teamId": teamId,
    }]),
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that was it but now even tho I'm getting 200 response I'm getting new error FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1). Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @kate_3dev don't know about that. but the way you parse the response does look a bit weird to me. I would expect you to just be able to do `json.decode(response.body);`. Usually you don't need to work with the bytes. No idea if that's related. If that doesn't help maybe try to do `print(response.body)` to see if the response is maybe not what you think it should be

Comment: I do this because the characters of the list I'm sending is in Greek